# Is there a version of Org Mode that would allow insertions of hlines and would adjust sum boundary hline references to change accordingly?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Is there a version of Org Mode that would allow insertions or
deletions of hlines and would adjust sum boundary hline references to change
accordingly?

The behavior that I would like to see is that the user could insert hlines anywhere in a spreadsheet and no existing sums (using vsum and hline references) would change (upon recalculation).  For deletion of hlines, existing sums would also not change--provided that the deleted hline was not one being used by a vsum formula.

Here is an example.  Start with this simple table.

```
|-----+----|  
|     |  1 |  
|     |  2 |  
|     |  3 |  
|     |  4 |  
|     |  5 |  
|     |  6 |  
|     |  7 |  
|-----+----|  
| sum | 28 |  
|     |    |  
#+TBLFM: @8$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

Add another hline above "1" and add "8" and "9" there.  The sum now
refers to "8" and "9".

```
|-----+----|  
|     |  8 |  
|     |  9 |  
|-----+----|  
|     |  1 |  
|     |  2 |  
|     |  3 |  
|     |  4 |  
|     |  5 |  
|     |  6 |  
|     |  7 |  
|-----+----|  
| sum | 17 |  
|     |    |  
#+TBLFM: @10$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

I have written my own elisp to adjust the #+TBLFM: line to read

#+TBLFM: @10$2=vsum(@II..@III)

in this case, but am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

org-version reports

Org mode version 9.5 (9.5-g0a86ad @/Users/alanwehmann/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.5/)

emacs-version reports

GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, NS appkit-1671.60 Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G95)) of 2020-08-12

NickD suggested that I should share my code here, so here it is:

(defadvice org-table-insert-hline (after mod-org-hline activate)
(if (ad-get-arg 0)
(aw-run-vsum-fix -1)
(aw-run-vsum-fix 0)))
;;(ad-deactivate 'org-table-insert-hline)
;;(ad-activate 'org-table-insert-hline)
;;(ad-deactivate 'org-table-kill-row)
;;(ad-activate 'org-table-kill-row)
(defadvice org-table-kill-row (around mod-kill-row activate)
(let ((aw-count 0)
(aw-buf (current-buffer))
is-hline)
(save-excursion
(beginning-of-line)
(when (looking-at org-table-hline-regexp)
(setq is-hline t))
ad-do-it)
(when is-hline
(save-excursion
(unwind-protect
(progn
(narrow-to-region (point-min) (point))
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (re-search-forward org-table-hline-regexp nil t)
(setq aw-count (1+ aw-count)))
(beginning-of-line))
(widen))
(aw-vsum-fix2 aw-buf aw-count))
(message "adjustments made to vsums for hline removal"))))
(defun aw-vsum-fix (aw-buf aw-line-no)
"fix vsum formulae in org spreadsheet when hline is inserted"
(interactive "bbuffer= \nnline #=")
(set-buffer aw-buf)
(let ((aw-end (make-marker))
aw-first aw-second aw-second-count aw-first-count)
(when (re-search-forward "#\+TBLFM:" nil t)
(set-marker aw-end (line-end-position))
(while (re-search-forward "vsum(@\(I+\)\.+@\(I+\)" aw-end t)
(setq aw-first (match-string 1)
aw-second (match-string 2)
aw-first-count (length aw-first)
aw-second-count (length aw-second))
(when (> aw-first-count aw-line-no)
(replace-match "\1I" t nil nil 1))
(when (> aw-second-count aw-line-no)
(replace-match "\2I" t nil nil 2))))))
(defun aw-vsum-fix2 (aw-buf aw-line-no)
"fix vsum formulae in org spreadsheet when hline is removed"
(interactive "bbuffer= \nnline #=")
(set-buffer aw-buf)
(let ((aw-end (make-marker))
aw-first aw-second aw-second-count aw-first-count)
(when (re-search-forward "#\+TBLFM:" nil t)
(set-marker aw-end (line-end-position))
(while (re-search-forward "vsum(@\(I+\)\.+@\(I+\)" aw-end t)
(setq aw-first (match-string 1)
aw-first-new (substring aw-first 0 -1)
aw-second (match-string 2)
aw-second-new (substring aw-second 0 -1)
aw-first-count (length aw-first)
aw-second-count (length aw-second))
(when (> aw-first-count aw-line-no)
(replace-match aw-first-new t nil nil 1))
(when (> aw-second-count aw-line-no)
(replace-match aw-second-new t nil nil 2))))))
(defun aw-run-vsum-fix (aw-count)
"count hlines before point"
(let ((aw-buf (current-buffer)))
(beginning-of-line)
(save-excursion
(unwind-protect
(progn
(narrow-to-region (point-min) (point))
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (re-search-forward org-table-hline-regexp nil t)
(setq aw-count (1+ aw-count))))
(widen))
(aw-vsum-fix aw-buf aw-count))
(message "adjustments made to vsums for hline addition")))

Comment: How is it supposed to know which hlines you want to consider in the `vsum`? IMO, the UI needed to specify what you want would become too complex: the simple manual intervention you did seems like the perfect solution to me.

Comment: Existing org code that adds a hline can be advised to make adjustments to vsums in hlines after that point.  Similarly for removing a hline.  My "beta' code for doing this is at this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFN8EfZmGrQfCcJhr4V4YZLEWR-LJ0kh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You should post your code as part of your question then.

Comment: What is not clear to me is what should change when you insert an hline and additional rows in the general case: if you call `org-table-insert-hline` at the top of the table, then you get a `vsum(@II..@III)` so it covers the old table, and adding rows between the first and second hlines does not affect the sum. OTOH, if you insert an hline in the middle or end of the table, then you get a `vsum(@I..@III)` covering the whole table and adding rows *will* affect the sum. Is that what you want? What I'm trying to say is: your question is unclear because the *speciification* is incomplete.

Comment: Another way to say it: if your code does what you want in all cases you are interested in, then go with your code and do not worry about mythical "better" ways. If it does not however, then you have to explain exactly what it should do in *all* cases.

Comment: The added paragraph does clarify things - thanks! OTOH, I don't think there is an existing mechanism to do this and I cannot think of anything better.